# cals - Removing left and right side-bearings of tabulars

Tags: tables, margins, cals

I try to write tabulars using the [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals)-package, but have run into a problem. I try to remove the side bearings (what you achieve by `>@{}` using [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array)). As far as I understand, I have to remove left padding of leftmost column by issuing a `\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}` at all leftmost cells in the first column, and restore it by `\cals@setpadding{Ag}\` immediately after the cell. The same goes for the right side.

This approach works in the body of the table as you will see from the enclosed picture. However, if I use the code in the heading (`\thead{<code>}`), the code does not compile. For the MWE enclosed, you get the error message indicating a command is not defined.

[image]

Here is the MWE (MnWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{50pt}{100pt}}
%
\thead{\bfseries\selectfont
\brow
    \makeatletter\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\makeatother % If you comment out line 16 and 18 the MWE compiles
    \cell{col1}
    \makeatletter\cals@setpadding{Ag}\makeatother % Comment out to compile
    \cell{col2}
\erow
\mdseries\selectfont}
\tfoot{\lastrule\nointerlineskip
\textit{\strut Some table caption
(not implemented: PartKofN)}\par}
%
\brow
    \makeatletter\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}\makeatother
    \cell{r1,col1}
    \makeatletter\cals@setpadding{Ag}\makeatother
    \makeatletter\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\makeatother
    \alignR\cell{r1,col2}
    \makeatletter\cals@setpadding{Ag}\makeatother
 \erow
%
\brow
    \alignL\cell{r2,col1}
    \alignR\cell{r2,col2}
\erow
%
\brow
    \alignL\cell{r3,col1}
    \cell{r3,col2}
\erow
%\tbreak{Manual table break!\strut\par}
\brow
    \cell{r4,col1}
    \cell{r4,col2}
\erow
%
\brow
    \cell{r5,col1}
    \cell{r5,col2}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Here is the log-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050)
entering extended mode
(C:/temp/test-cals-ex2.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(C:\miktex\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\miktex\texmfs\install\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\miktex\texmfs\install\tex/latex/cals\cals.sty)
No file test-cals-ex2.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cals 
                 @paddingL
l.15 }

?
```

A bug or a user error?

Comment: You are missing a ``\`` in `makeatletter`: `\brow makeatletter\setlength{\cals@paddingL`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That is just a typo in the question, the source code is correct. I have also corrected two other typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catcode changes (`\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`, and the like) will not work as macro arguments. You are doing `\thead{... \makeatletter\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}}`. This is tokenized as `\makeatletter\setlength{\cals @paddingL}{0pt}` (notice the space after `\cals`). You need to move `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` outside `\thead`.

You can also reduce a bunch of the `\makeatletter<code with @>\makeatother` and use one `\makeatletter` when the all the code with `@` starts and a `\makeatother` when it all ends.

Also, `\bfseries` already does `\selectfont`, so the latter is redundant here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{50pt}{100pt}}
%
\makeatletter
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}% If you comment out line 16 and 18 the MWE compiles
    \cell{col1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}% Comment out to compile
    \cell{col2}
\erow
\mdseries}
\makeatother
\tfoot{\lastrule\nointerlineskip
\textit{\strut Some table caption
(not implemented: PartKofN)}\par}
%
\makeatletter% @=11
\brow
    \setlength{\cals@paddingL}{0pt}%
    \cell{r1,col1}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
    \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}
    \alignR\cell{r1,col2}
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\erow
\makeatother% @=12
%
\brow
    \alignL\cell{r2,col1}
    \alignR\cell{r2,col2}
\erow
%
\brow
    \alignL\cell{r3,col1}
    \cell{r3,col2}
\erow
%\tbreak{Manual table break!\strut\par}
\brow
    \cell{r4,col1}
    \cell{r4,col2}
\erow
%
\brow
    \cell{r5,col1}
    \cell{r5,col2}
\erow
\end{calstable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The example was taken from the documentation (to be sure that I did not introduced some stupid mistakes, which I unintentionally did :)).

Comment: @Sveinung A wise man once said: never read the documentation :-)

Comment: I always read the documentation three times before I start. :(. Follow up: If I start the calstable with a `\makeatletter` and end it with a `\makeatother`, will I run the risk that I suddenly run into trouble because of the content of a cell?

Comment: @Sveinung (About the documentation, it was a joke; it's good to read it once in a while :) I find it rather unlikely that you'll get in trouble for using `\makeatletter` there. Unless you have some input file which contains something like `\some@macro` and you need it to be `\some<space>@macro`. Otherwise you should be fine.

Comment: I understood the joke. Another wise man said that you learn as long as you live. So the conclusion (after have read your answer) is that I am still alive. Have a nice week-end!

Comment: @Sveinung That's a good saying ;) Nice weekend to you too!