# How to resolve this clash between multirow/multicolumn and cellcoloring?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, colortbl

I am trying to put together a little table, but I fail to have the lines between cells displayed correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}


\begin{document}

\centerline{
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor{mycolor}\multirow{2}{*}{}&\multirow{2}{*}{}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{b}\\ \cline{3-5} \rowcolor{mycolor}\multirow{2}{*}{}&\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{3ex}[3ex]{a}}&c&d&e\\ \hline\hline
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline\hline
\rowcolor{mycolor}entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the lines are displayed in a strange way. There should be one between "b" and "c/d/e" (through \cline{3-5}) and between entries 3 and 4 of the last line and so on. I already needed some workaround so that "a" doesn't get covered by the color. If I delete the color commands in the above code, it also looks fine. What workaround does the trick now?

Comment: This is well known issues. Your lines are there (magnify table image in pdf viewer), However, your pdf viewer due to its artifacts is not able to show them correctly. In m:y `sumatra`, i can see all lines ... There is not much what you can do

Comment: @Zarko the lines might be in the PDF but they are not visible in print, the rendering of your PDF viewer is wrong. The cline will be covered completely by a following `\cellcolor` or `\rulecolor`. This is true because every `\cline` issues a `\noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}`, so that it is possible to place multiple `\cline`s in the same height.

Comment: @Zarko if you want to see what a PDF really looks like, you should use `xpdf`. I know its not that comfortable, and I don't use it for regular PDF viewing, too, but it is the most precisely rendering viewer that I know of.

Comment: @Zarko that `\rulecolor` in my first comment should've been `\rowcolor` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Definition for documents

As usual, this type of tabular is very easy to build, if you have the possibility to use [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals). The example is 123% magnification in Adobe.

I have updated the code and incorporated a better column width calculation so that the tabular spreads to the whole text width. In addition, I made two new shortcuts (`\tp` and `\lp`) to remove the top and bottom cell padding in the narrow rows. However, it was only possible to remove top padding. I also narrowed the height and width of the narrow rows and columns, from eight points to four and a half points. Then I got rid of some bad box warnings disappear. If I removed bottom bearing, for som reasos the cells below did not looked good, even though I turned restored the cell padding after the last narrow cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {4.5pt}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {4.5pt}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 4

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\orange{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{orange}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tp{\ifdim\cals@paddingT=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0pt}\fi}

\def\bp{\ifdim\cals@paddingB=0.0pt\relax    % Bottom padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0pt}\fi}


% R1H1
\thead{%
\brow
    \orange\nc{lrt}\orange
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \orange\nc{lrt}\orange
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \orange\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil b}\orange
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \orange\nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil a}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil c}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil d}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil e}\orange
\erow
\brow
    \tp\lb\rb\cell{} % Switch off top and bottom padding, left and right border
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\lb\rb % Switch on top and bottom padding, left and right border
    \ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt
    \tp
\erow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
\erow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
\erow
\brow
    \bp\tp\lb\rb\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\lb\rb
    \ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt
    \tp
\erow
\brow
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

### beamer-compatible definition

The setup and definition of shortcuts above do not work in a [beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) environment, because beamer slides are commands and the texts are arguments to those commands. Then you cannot define/redefine commands with `@` by using `\makeatletter-\makeatother`. I tried to use the frame-environment to build the slide, but it did not work. Instead you have to move the setup and all definitions of shortcuts and commands that have `@`, outside of the slide-command. For further explanation, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492456/9632)

I have moved all setup to the preamble. Also, I defined a shortcut for rowheight:

```
\newcommand{\rowh}{\ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt}
```

and replace the two lines in the body

```
\ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt
```

with the command `\rowh`. That shortcut can also be defined with a parameter for the row height, instead of hard coding the height:

```
\newcommand{\rowh}[1]{\ht\cals@current@row=#1}
```

Then you write `\rowh{4.5pt}` or whatever to fix the height of a row.

Mowing the definition to the preamble have implicate that the setup has effect for all tabulars. If this a problem for you, instead you can defined new commands with parameters for all the setup commands (as the `\rowh`-command), and use those new commands in each tabular's preamble instead.

Here is a working MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor, cals}

\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

% cals shortcuts for spanning celles
\let\nc=\nullcell
\let\sc=\spancontent

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

% Shortcut switches
\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
\def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\orange{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{orange}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tp{\ifdim\cals@paddingT=0.0pt\relax    % Top padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingT}{0pt}\fi}

\def\bp{\ifdim\cals@paddingB=0.0pt\relax    % Bottom padding switch (off-on)
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingB}{0pt}\fi}

\newcommand{\rowh}{\ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\frame{\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {4.5pt}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {4.5pt}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth-9pt)/5\relax}
            }



% R1H1
\thead{%
\brow
    \orange\nc{lrt}\orange
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \orange\nc{lrt}\orange
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \orange\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil b}\orange
\erow
}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \orange\nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil a}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil c}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil d}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil e}\orange
\erow
\brow
    \tp\lb\rb\cell{} % Switch off top and bottom padding, left and right border
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\lb\rb % Switch on top and bottom padding, left and right border
    \rowh
    \tp
\erow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
\erow
\brow
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \cell{}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
\erow
\brow
    \bp\tp\lb\rb\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\lb\rb
    \rowh
    \tp
\erow
\brow
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
    \cell{}
    \orange\alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}
    \alignC\cell{\vfil entry}\orange
\erow
\end{calstable}\par
}

\frame{\frametitle{}
\begin{lemma}
  If $d$ is a $a$ then it is 
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  wfmkrf
\end{proof}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is extremely flexible!

Comment: I don't know why, but I don't think that is "easy", but that might because I'm not used to the `cals` syntax.

Comment: @Skillmon Easy is subjective. I may have blurred the syntax by using shortcuts. But cals works on a cell by cell basis, in principle. Outside a cell, commands take effect until they are changed, or switched off. This works well on a row, but not on columns. Spanning cells can be a challenge, because you have to explicitly mark every cell if they are left, right, top or bottom of a span. cals has shortcomings, too. For example when it comes to colourisation of rules (not possible). And I miss siunitx columns when setting up mathematical tabular. So I use both standard LaTeX and cals.

Comment: I'm afraid there's still a problem: Your code works well in a separate document, but including it on a slide in my beamer presentation leads to the error "Use of \cals doesn't match its definition. You can't use "\prevdepth" in horizontal mode". Do you know what this is about?

Comment: @Mau314 I solved the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Your exact code with \documentclass{beamer} and the table on a frame still produces the error.

Comment: @Mau314 You have to move the definitions that contain a @ to the preamble of presentation, before \begin{document}. It seems that beamer do something even if you construct the frames as environment. See the code in my example two.

Comment: @Mau314 Also, define a shortcut for rowheight, `\newcommand{\rowh}{\ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt}` and replace the two lines in the body `\ht\cals@current@row=4.5pt` with the command `\rowh`. That shortcut can also be defined with a parametre for the row height, instead of hardcoding the height: `\newcommand{\rowh}[1]{\ht\cals@current@row=#1}`. Then you write `\rowh{4.5pt}` or whatever to fix the height of a row.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For this to look right we have to make sure the `\cline` doesn't get overprinted by the following cell's or row's colour. To achieve this we have to call `\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}` after the `\cline`. Unfortunately this will leave white rules in those cells which are not covered by a `\cline`, therefore we have to put a coloured `\cline` in those cells. But unfortunately a coloured `\cline` would also colour over the vertical rules and the white space between the doubled vertical rules in your table. Therefore we have to modify our coloured `\cline` such that it cares for vertical rules.

The following implements `\fillnonclinedcell`, which puts a coloured rule in a single cell and which cares for vertical rules. To care for a single vertical rule to the left of the cell use the first optional argument with `|` inside, to care for a double vertical rule to the left use `||` in that argument. Keep in mind that rules always belong to the cell left of it, so the only cell in which you should need the first optional argument is in the first column. The second optional argument specifies which type of vertical rule is right of the cell, again `|` and `||` as arguments cover the corresponding vertical rule definitions.

You can also fill multiple adjacent cells if there is no vertical rule separating them using `<num1>-<num2>` as the second mandatory argument instead of a single cell number.

**EDIT:** To get `\multirow` right in coloured cells you should leave the first row empty and put the `\multirow` command in the second row with `{-2}` as the height argument, I've edited the code below to cover that. And you don't need to place a `\multirow` with an empty text, just leave those cells empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\fillnonclinedcell@rule[1]
  {%
    \leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hskip#1
  }
\usepackage{xparse}
% borrow a string compare function from expl3
\expandafter\let\expandafter
  \fillnonclinedcell@ifstr\csname str_if_eq:nnTF\endcsname
\newcommand*\fillnonclinedcell
  {%
    \omit
    \fillnonclinedcell@args
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\fillnonclinedcell@args{mO{}>{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}mO{}}
  {%
    \fillnonclinedcell@do{#1}{#2}#3{#4}%
  }
\newcommand\fillnonclinedcell@do[5]
  {%
    \@multicnt#3
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne
      \@firstofone{&\omit}%
    \fi
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
      {%
        \@multicnt\z@
      }
      {%
        \@multicnt#4
        \advance\@multicnt-#3
      }%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \fillnonclinedcell@ifstr{#2}{|}
      {%
        \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
      }
      {%
        \fillnonclinedcell@ifstr{#2}{||}
          {%
            \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
            \hskip\doublerulesep
            \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
          }
          {}%
      }%
    \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \fillnonclinedcell@rule{0pt plus 1fill}%
    \endgroup
    \fillnonclinedcell@ifstr{#5}{|}
      {%
        \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
      }
      {%
        \fillnonclinedcell@ifstr{#5}{||}
          {%
            \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
            \hskip\doublerulesep
            \fillnonclinedcell@rule\arrayrulewidth
          }
          {}%
      }%
    \cr
    \noalign{\vskip-\arrayrulewidth}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\centerline{
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor{mycolor}&&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{b}\\ 
% to get the `\cline` right we have to draw coloured `\cline`s for the ones we
% don't want
\fillnonclinedcell{mycolor}[|]{1}[||]
\fillnonclinedcell{mycolor}{2}[||]
\cline{3-5}
% make the `\cline`s visible
\noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}
\rowcolor{mycolor}&\multirow{-2}{*}{a}&c&d&e\\ \hline\hline
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline\hline
\rowcolor{mycolor}entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Rendering of this image was done with `xpdf` at 800% magnification, screenshot cropped with Gimp*

Comment: +1! good to know this workaround.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I'm afraid it doesn't look better in my case. The pdfs produced through TeXworks and also Overleaf look essentially as before (up-to-date Adobe Reader). Also, Overleaf shows the message "_ must be used in math mode" at your line "\fillnonclinedcell@ifstr\csname str_if_eq:nnTF\endcsname"

Comment: Well, in fact it depends on the zoom factor; I'll also try rendering with xpdf as you did when I have the opportunity... However, even if this is going to work, I find this behaviour inacceptable - good to have people like you!

Comment: @Mau314 the linter (syntax checker) of Overleaf doesn't use a TeX engine to do its magic, instead it tries to parse the code with a different language. The advantage is that the performance is good/acceptable (a complete TeX run every time to find the errors would bloat the system), the disadvantage is that it doesn't always parse everything right (e.g. a `_` inside of `\csname` is totally fine in TeX as long as the `_` wasn't made active). You can exempt certain lines from the linting by surrounding them with `%%begin novalidate` and `%%end novalidate`.

Comment: @Mau314 see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_for_part_of_a_file

Comment: Thank you again, @Skillmon, clearly you also provided a solution - the first one even.

Comment: @Mau314 it's your decision which one you accept and you shouldn't accept just the first answer, but the one helping you the most. My answer is more of an attempt to show the backgrounds of what's going on in a regular LaTeX tabular and why the things don't work, the effect that it spit out a solution is just a nice extra (I never looked at it, but `hhline` might work in a similar way as the code I posted).

Answer (score 5):

How about this layout, with `hhline`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

{ \centering\arrayrulecolor{mycolor}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c||c|c|c|}
\rowcolor{mycolor}& &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{b}\\
\noalign{\vspace{-0.4pt}}\hhline{|-||-||>{\arrayrulecolor{FireBrick}}--->{\arrayrulecolor{mycolor}}|}
\rowcolor{mycolor} & \multirow{-2}{*}{a}&\multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{FireBrick}\vline}}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{FireBrick}\vline}}{d}&e\\
\hhline{:=::=::=:=:=:}
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\
\hhline{:=::=::=:=:=:}
entry&entry&entry&entry&entry\\%\arrayrulecolor{black}
\hhline{:=::=::=:=:=:}
\rowcolor{mycolor}entry & entry & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{FireBrick}\vline}}{entry} &\multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{FireBrick}\vline}}{ entry} & entry \\
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very effective and it's good to know the hhline package. It seems to me that there's the same slight disadvantage as to Skillmon's solution, namely the sensitivity to the zoom factor.

Comment: I've updated my code, to remove the very thin horizontal white lines between rows 1 and 2. Please  see if it's OK for you now.

Comment: Thanks, it's even better now. Zooming sensitivity still remains though. From your and Skillmon's contributions I'm beginning to feel that this is really - in a sense - a shortcoming of tabular.

Comment: @Mau314 If it is a shortcoming or a feature can be debated, because LaTeX is focused on good typography, and using colours and rules together in tabulars is not good typography. However, if your customers demand colour and rules, you have a problem with tabular and friends. The author of cals solves this problem by printing the rules last, which may cause other problems (I have not run into them). But if you need coloured cells and coloured rules together, as far as I am aware of, no LaTeX package can help you to ‘perfect’ results.

Comment: @Mau314 if anything it's not a shortcoming of LaTeX, but of your PDF viewer's rendering. There are no seams in between the lines, but the viewer does approximate each line individually on to the available (sub)pixels, which results in seams if that approximation sets the border of one line to a pixel row not adjacent to pixels of the border of the next line.